# Bootstrap navbar how can i underline with a line with spaces in both sides?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm trying to make a menu with bootstrap 3, I'm actually using code like this:

```
        <section id="menu">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="logo.jpg" alt="logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 nana">
                    <p>Some other menu</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                    <p>Some other menu</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                    <p>Some other menu</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                    <p>Some other menu</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                    <p>Some other menu</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

But I want to achieve this:

[image]

how can i put the lines , I use "border-bottom" property but it expands all the column, I just want to have the separations of each menu, if I apply margins it just broke the menu.

Is there a way to achieve this? 
I'm thinking of using :before, :after,

But I don't know, anybody can help me!

Comment: Are you a beginner in `twitter-bootstrap-3`?

Comment: for menu purposes you should use navbar class https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Use https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar to build your navigation menu. If you don't like it then create your own custom list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [css ::after Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp) for creating this type of thing.

```
.col-sm-2::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 3px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: #aaa;
    transition: all .35s;
}
.col-sm-2:hover::after {
    background: #68c122;
}
```

Here is a small [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksh74ymv/) to get started.
But I strongly suggest Using `<nav class="navbar" role="navigation"></nav>`
for a creating navigation.

Comment: Thank you! this is the solution!! thank you thank you thank you!!

Comment: Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo class

```css
ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.two:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.three:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.four:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">Menu Text</a></li><!--
 --><li class="two"><a href="#">Menu Text</a></li><!--
 --><li class="three"><a href="#">Menu Text</a></li><!--
 --><li class="four"><a href="#">Menu Text</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Just add

```
margin-left: 2px;
margin-right: 2px; // change the values based on your requirement
```

for the menu items (in your case it will be the div to which you are adding border-bottom).

**USE NAVBAR**

But looking at your code I would like to suggest you to build your menu the correct way using bootstraps `navbar` component.

Read more about it here:

https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: If i add margin left and right the responsive design brokes! :( thanks for your answer